# how to take backup of texlive directory and steps after backup

Tags: installing

I have installed texlive on Windows 10 and took me several hours to do this.
Approximately 6 Gb of packages were downloaded.
Now I have a folder C:\texlive
If I take a backup of this folder then my assumption is my installation is backed up.
If I have for some reason to install texlive again then just copying this folder to C drive will do the needful. Or I need to do something else to do installation. Let me know how to resume things in case of using this backup directory on a new system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tlmgr` to make a backup:

```
tlmgr backup --all --backupdir directory
```

and

```
tlmgr restore --all --backupdir directory
```

to restore the backup.

Or you use a portable installation to switch systems: https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-420004.2