# How do I reinstall Tex Live from a backup? (Windows)

Tags: texlive, installing

I don't have access to a large amount of internet at the moment and am trying to install it from a backup.

I didn't think at the time of the original installation to make it portable sadly, however I would like to convert it too one in the new install.

I initially researched this issue and found that I can backup Tex Live using the tlmgr command, so that is what I did.

Link: [how to take backup of texlive directory and steps after backup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531640/how-to-take-backup-of-texlive-directory-and-steps-after-backup)

Now the problem is using the restore command when I don't have the tlmgr package installed.

To try and fix this I did a minimal install hoping that I would have the tlmgr command, however this was not the case.

I'm not sure what to do now and haven't been able to find anyone else online with the same issue.

Alternatively if there is a way to convert my current install to a portable one that would be great.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would advise a new installation from scratch.  For one thing, the installation also affects the registry.  For another, the executables tend to be machine dependent.  I only back up my user files.

Comment: Damn rightio, I'll have to wait until I have more internet available, thanks!

Also is a portable installation advisable or does that mess with stuff?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a portable installation.  If you have a LAN (WiFi) you can leave it one one machine.  In most cases file I/O is minimal.